# How to adjust the same height for all the buttons dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm generating my own `Button` views (non extended from android `Button` class).

The height of the button depends of the size of the phone screen. This app should show the same height for all the buttons of the screen on all the phones, with all the `screen` sizes possible.

Then, i should known the height size of the  button before adding it to the `layout`, but i dont know wich size it haves until it is painted on the screen.

How can i put the same height on all my buttons `dynamically` depending of the screen size?

thanks

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne ,Did u try out the solution?

Comment: It is not I that is the OP, I just edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i did it with onLayout and layout call with my method

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You can consider taking a phone of dimension say 320 x480 and check whats the best width and height for single button on it.The class given below calculates the width and height based on the devices width and height. Say you come to know that you need 40 as width/height for your button , then just pass 40 as a parameter to calculateWidth()/calculateHeight()
function for the class given below.At runtime the width and height will get set dynamically.

```
public class DimensionManager {

    private int _screenWidth;
    private int _screenHeight;
    private int _baseScreenWidth = 320;
    private int _baseScreenHeight = 480;

    public DimensionManager(Activity act) {
        WindowManager w = act.getWindowManager();
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        _screenWidth = d.getWidth();
        _screenHeight = d.getHeight();
    }
/**
 * 
 * @param baseViewWidth Width considering a base Layout.
 * @return Returns corresponding width for the device and orientation.
 */
    public int calculateWidth(int baseViewWidth) {
        return (baseViewWidth * _screenWidth) / _baseScreenWidth;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param baseViewHeight Height considering a base Layout.
     * @return  Returns corresponding height for the device and orientation.
     */
    public int calculateHeight(int baseViewHeight) {
        return (baseViewHeight * _screenHeight) / _baseScreenHeight;
    }
}
```